# Categorize a column and count the number of warnings in a column

Tags: awk

I am having a file called **out.txt** as below:

```
Statement 1                        Statement 2  Statement 3    Statement 4
The declaration is not done         /   Exp     /   *       /  This is expected
The declaration is starting/started /   St      /   *       /  This is not expected
The declaration is not yet designed /   Yt      /   &       /  This is a major one
The declaration is confirmed        /   Exp     /   *       /  This is okay
The declaration is not confirmed    /   Ntp     /   &       /  This is a major issue
```

I need to sum up and categorize from column 3 (Statement 3), if it is * as **Warning** and if it is **&** it is a **Error** as below:

```
Out:
Warnings:
    Exp : 2
    St  : 1
Total : 3
Errors:
    Yt : 1
    Ntp: 1
Total :2
```

I tried below code, but not getting the exact output:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " " ;
File="out.txt"
for z in out.txt;
do
if grep -q "&" $z/"$File"; then
echo "$z:";
awk -F' / ' 
     { a[$2]++ }
     END{ for(j in a){ print j, a[j]; s=s+a[j] };
 print "Total :", s}' out.txt
else 
echo "$z:";
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** Since OP confirmed that there are NO keywords for errors it should be decided by `&` keyword in 2nd last field of line then try following.

```
awk -F'/' '
match($0,/[[:space:]]+\/[^/]*[[:space:]]+\//){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+|\//,"",val)
  str=$(NF-1)
  gsub(/ +/,"",str)
  if(str=="&"){
     countEr[val]++
  }
  else{
     countSu[val]++
  }
  val=str=""
}
END{
  print "Out:" ORS "Warings:"
  for(i in countSu){
     print "\t"i,countSu[i]
     sumSu+=countSu[i]
  }
  print "Total:"sumSu
  print "Errors:"
  for(i in countEr){
     print "\t"i,countEr[i]
     sumEr+=countEr[i]
  }
  print "Total:"sumEr
}' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Generic solution where one could give all errors names in a variable and then we need NOT to put it all conditions manually like my previous solution does. Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v errors="Ntp,Yt"  '
BEGIN{
  num=split(errors,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     errorVal[arr[i]]
  }
}
match($0,/[[:space:]]+\/[^/]*[[:space:]]+\//){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+|\//,"",val)
  if(val in errorVal){
     countEr[val]++
  }
  else{
     countSu[val]++
  }
  val=""
}
END{
  print "Out:" ORS "Warings:"
  for(i in countSu){
     print "\t"i,countSu[i]
     sumSu+=countSu[i]
  }
  print "Total:"sumSu
  print "Errors:"
  for(i in countEr){
     print "\t"i,countEr[i]
     sumEr+=countEr[i]
  }
  print "Total:"sumEr
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[[:space:]]+\/[^/]*[[:space:]]+\//){        ##Using match function to match space slash space and slash here as per samples to get value.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                       ##Saving sub-string into variable val from RSTART to RLENGTH here.
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+|\//,"",val)                      ##Removing spaces and slashes with NULL in val here.
  if(val=="Ntp" || val=="Yt"){                        ##Checking condition if value is either Ntp PR Yt then do following.
     countEr[val]++                                   ##Increase count for array countEr with 1 with index of val here.
  }
  else{                                               ##Else do following.
     countSu[val]++                                   ##Increase count of array countSu with index of val here.
  }
  val=""                                              ##Nullifying val here.
}
END{                                                  ##Starting END block of this program here.
  print "Out:" ORS "Warnings:"                        ##Printing string Out new line and Warnings here.
  for(i in countSu){                                  ##Traversing through countSu here.
     print "\t"i,countSu[i]                           ##Printing tab index of array and value of CountSu here.
     sumSu+=countSu[i]                                ##Keep on adding value of countSu current item into sumSu variable here.
  }
  print "Total:"sumSu                                 ##Printing Total string with sumSu value here.
  print "Errors:"                                     ##Printing string Errors here.
  for(i in countEr){                                  ##Traversing through countEr here.
     print "\t"i,countEr[i]                           ##Printing tab index i and countEr value here.
     sumEr+=countEr[i]                                ##Keep on adding value of countEr current item into sumEr variable here.
  }
  print "Total:"sumEr                                 ##Printing Total string with sumEr value here.
}'  Input_file                                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: The list of errors will not be only two**( Ntp and yt)**, other errors may also come. It is identified as a error if in column three**(statement three )**there is **&** in it.

Comment: @Rama, ok please try my EDIT2 solution and let me know then?

Comment: One doubt.. What if we have **|** (pipeline symbol) as a delimiter in between statement one and statement two columns?

Comment: @Rama, than you may need to change field separator to `-F'|'`(not tested since solution was written as per shown samples only) and change `match($0,/[[:space:]]+\|[^/]*[[:space:]]+\|/)` and change 
 `gsub(/[[:space:]]+|\|/,"",val)` in my EDIT2 solution.

Comment: Thanks for the changes you suggested, its working fine wih | symbol.

Comment: One doubt, whats the use of this one : str=$(NF-1)

Comment: @Rama, saving 2nd last field value of current line into str variable, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

another gawk alternative - relies on gawk's "true multi-dimensional arrays":
`$ cat tst.awk:`

```
BEGIN {
  FS="[[:blank:]]/[[:blank:]]"
  OFS=" : "
}
FNR>1{
   gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "", $2)
   gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "", $3)
   a[$3][$2]++
}
END {
  #PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"
  print "Out" OFS
  for(i in a) {
    print (i=="*"?"Warnings":"Errors") OFS
    t=0
    for(j in a[i]) {
      print "\t" j, a[i][j]
      t+=a[i][j]
    }
    print "Total", t
    t=0
  }
}
```

`gawk -tst.awk myFile` results in:

```
Out :
Warnings :
        St : 1
        Exp : 2
Total : 3
Errors :
        Ntp : 1
        Yt : 1
Total : 2
```