# grep for a particular string and count the number of fatals and errors

Tags: regex, awk

I am having a file called violations.txt as below:

```
column1                  column2      column3         column4                    Situation
Data is preesnt         |  Bgn      | Status (!)    | There are no current runs | Critical level
Data is not existing    |  Nbgn     | Status (*)    | There are runs            | Medium level
Data limit is exceeded  |  Gnp      | Status (!)    | The runs are not present  | Higher level
Dats existing|present   |  Esp      | Status (*)    | The runs are present      | Normal|Higher level
```

I need the output like this:

```
violations.txt:
Fatal:
    Bgn : 1
    Gnp : 1
Total number of fatals : 2  
Errors:
    Nbgn : 1
    Esp  : 1
Total number of errors : 2
```

I am trying to execute if the file **violations.txt** conatins in the column3 the word **Status (!)** as a fatal and if it contains the word **Status(*)** as a warning and also the count of it.

I tried the below code but not getting the exact output:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
echo " " ;
File="violations.txt"
for g in $File;
do
awk -F' +\\| +' 
if "$3"== "Status (!) /"  "$File" ; then
'BEGIN{ getline; getline }
truncate -s -1 "$File"
echo "$g:";
         { a[$2]++ }
     END{ for(i in a){ print i, a[i]; s=s+a[i] };
        print "Total numer of fatals:", s}' violations.txt
else 
echo "$g:";
'BEGIN{ getline; getline }
truncate -s -1 "$File"
echo "$g:";
         { a[$2]++ }
     END{ for(i in a){ print i, a[i]; s=s+a[i] };
        print "Total numer of errors:", s}' violations.txt
fi
done
```

Comment: You're mixing awk and shell constructs in 1 script. awk and shell are 2 completely different tools with their own syntax, semantics, and scopes. You can call a shell script from awk (and vice-versa) just like you can call a shell or awk script from C but you can't just mix both languages together any more than you can mix C and Fortran syntax in a single program. Try to find a basic shell tutorial and a basic awk tutorial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Categorize a column and count the number of warnings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670440/categorize-a-column-and-count-the-number-of-warnings-in-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Written and tested in
https://ideone.com/rsVIV4

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="\\|"
}
FNR==1{  next  }
/Status \(\!\)/{
  match($0,/\| +[a-zA-Z]+ +\| Status/)
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/\| +| +\| Status/,"",val)
  countEr[val]++
  val=""
}
/Status \(\*\)/{
  match($0,/\| +[a-zA-Z]+ +\| Status/)
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/\| +| +\| Status/,"",val)
  countSu[val]++
  val=""
}
END{
  print "Fatal:"
  for(i in countEr){
     print "\t"i,countEr[i]
     sumEr+=countEr[i]
  }
  print "Total number of fatal:"  sumEr
  for(i in countSu){
     print "\t"i,countSu[i]
     sumSu+=countSu[i]
  }
  print "Total number of errors:"sumSu
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                      ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS="\\|"                                  ##Setting field separator as | for all lines here.
}
FNR==1{  next  }                            ##Checking condition if FNR==1 then go next and do not do anything on this line.
/Status \(\!\)/{                            ##Checking condition if line contains Status (!) then do following.
  match($0,/\| +[a-zA-Z]+ +\| Status/)      ##Using match function to match pipe space letters space and | space and Status string here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)             ##Creating sub-string from current line here.
  gsub(/\| +| +\| Status/,"",val)           ##Globally substituting pipe space and Status keyword with NULL in val here.
  countEr[val]++                            ##Creating array countEr with index of val and increment its count with 1 here.
  val=""                                    ##Nullifying val here.
}
/Status \(\*\)/{                            ##Checking condition if line contains Status (*) then do following.
  match($0,/\| +[a-zA-Z]+ +\| Status/)      ##Using match function to match pipe space letters space and | space and Status string here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)             ##Creating sub-string from current line here.
  gsub(/\| +| +\| Status/,"",val)           ##Globally substituting pipe space and Status keyword with NULL in val here.
  countSu[val]++                            ##Creating array countSu with index of val and increment its count with 1 here.
  val=""                                    ##Nullifying val here.
}
END{                                        ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print "Fatal:"                            ##Printing Fatal keyword here.
  for(i in countEr){                        ##Traversing through countEr here.
     print "\t"i,countEr[i]                 ##Printing tab i and value of countEr with index i here.
     sumEr+=countEr[i]                      ##Creating sumEr and keep adding value of countEr here.
  }
  print "Total number of fatal:"  sumEr     ##Printing string Total number of fatal/l and value of sumEr here.
  for(i in countSu){                        ##Traversing through countSu here.
     print "\t"i,countSu[i]                 ##Printing tab i and value of countSu with index i here.
     sumSu+=countSu[i]                      ##Creating sumSu and keep adding value of countSu here.
  }
  print "Total number of errors:"sumSu      ##Printing string Total number of errors: with value of sumSu here.
}
' Input_file                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Written this on mobile as of now, will write detailed explanation once I am in my server cheers.

Comment: Thanks,the script is working fine this one and also the previous one, but now I am not able to see the previous code, can you please explain both.

Comment: @Kavitha, I didn't get which previous code? As mentioned in my comment my laptop got some issues so I am writing these in mobile will try to add whatever explanation I could cheers

Comment: Okay and thanks for spending your valuable time on this one.

Comment: @Kavitha, will add explanation once I am on system on mobile writing explanation is not at all easy :)

Comment: Can you please take time on this and explain the code once, and I am having a parent directory and in that parent directory I am having 10 sub-directories , each sub-directory will be having this violations.txt file, my doubt is can we skip execution of the script for a particular sub-directory/violations.txt file or we cannot ?

Comment: @Kavitha, I will add explanation in few mins but as mentioned previously my laptop having issues I need to write it on mobile. Also for directory wise running it that was not mentioned on your question do it was written based on your question only, for running on multiple places you can use find command with it. But it's better not to edit questions and answers here since it will confuse users here, give me few mins will add detailed explanation here.

Comment: @Kavitha, I have added detailed explanation in my solution now request you to please have a look to it and let me know in case of any queries cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220842/discussion-between-kavitha-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 3):

Haven't we already covered this in a somewhat different reincarnation?

`$ cat tst.awk`

```
BEGIN {
  FS="[[:blank:]][|][[:blank:]]"
  OFS=" : "
}
FNR>1{
   gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "", $2)
   gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "", $3)
   a[$3][$2]++
}
END {
  #PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"
  print "Out" OFS
  for(i in a) {
    print ($i~/*/?"Fatal":"Error") OFS
    t=0
    for(j in a[i]) {
      print "\t" j, a[i][j]
      t+=a[i][j]
    }
    print "Total", t
    t=0
  }
}
```

running `awk -f tst.awk myFile` results in:

```
Out :
Fatal :
        Gnp : 1
        Bgn : 1
Total : 2
Fatal :
        Esp : 1
        Nbgn : 1
Total : 2
```

Comment: we covered it yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670440/categorize-a-column-and-count-the-number-of-warnings-in-a-column/63671533#63671533)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for various extensions and using the fact that your input is fixed-width fields:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS="24 1 11 1 15 1 27 1 *"
}
NR>1 {
    type = ($5 ~ /!/ ? "Fatal" : "Error")
    keyTot[type][gensub(/\s/,"","g",$3)]++
    tot[type]++
}
END {
    for (type in tot) {
        print type ":"
        for (key in keyTot[type]) {
            print "    " key " : " keyTot[type][key]
        }
        print "Total number of " type " : " tot[type]+0
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Error:
    Esp : 1
    Nbgn : 1
Total number of Error : 2
Fatal:
    Gnp : 1
    Bgn : 1
Total number of Fatal : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks very badly formatted, from a computer point of view, let me explain you why:

```
column1                  column2      column3         column4                    Situation
Data is preesnt         |  Bgn      | Status (!)    | There are no current runs | Critical level
Data is not existing    |  Nbgn     | Status (*)    | There are runs            | Medium level
Data limit is exceeded  |  Gnp      | Status (!)    | The runs are not present  | Higher level
Dats existing|present   |  Esp      | Status (*)    | The runs are present      | Normal|Higher level
```

The locations of the first character of the headers of columns 1, 3 and 4 are equal to the first characters of the contents, but for columns 2 and 5, this is not the case.
You are using the pipe character "|" as a separator for your columns, but also for a separator within the columns themselves. This combination is very bad for automatic parsin, based on "|" character as a separator.

Therefore I have following proposals for improving your file:

First let's take care of the column headings first characters:

```
column1                    column2    column3         column4                     Situation
Data is preesnt         |  Bgn      | Status (!)    | There are no current runs | Critical level
Data is not existing    |  Nbgn     | Status (*)    | There are runs            | Medium level
Data limit is exceeded  |  Gnp      | Status (!)    | The runs are not present  | Higher level
Dats existing|present   |  Esp      | Status (*)    | The runs are present      | Normal|Higher level
```

If you agree on this, you might use the amount of characters for reading your columns.

Second, let's change the internal separator (replace it by a slash character):

```
column1                   column2     column3         column4                     Situation
Data is preesnt         |  Bgn      | Status (!)    | There are no current runs | Critical level
Data is not existing    |  Nbgn     | Status (*)    | There are runs            | Medium level
Data limit is exceeded  |  Gnp      | Status (!)    | The runs are not present  | Higher level
Dats existing/present   |  Esp      | Status (*)    | The runs are present      | Normal/Higher level
```

Do you agree with my first or second proposal? If yes, please adapt your question (by adding the agreed proposal), this will make everything easier to handle.

Comment: on the verge of NAA

Comment: @DaemonPainter: who is NAA?

Comment: Assuming we can modify the input file, I can't see the attempt to solve the issue at hand, even on the modified input. Resulting in this not being an answer, but rather a comment

Comment: @DaemonPainter: in case the requester agrees to use the slash as an internal separator, the `awk -F "|"` could be used for handling this question in a fairly easy manner.

Comment: @Dominique you're looking at the OPs input as being `|`-separated, but if it's actually just fixed width fields as it appears to be then it's easy to parse as such and there's no reason to change any characters.